# How to Change color and remove arrow mark?

Tags: angular

Job box is just a label and normal dropdown...
Plant is multiselect drop down..
i need to remove plant 'down arrow mark' and put job 'arrow mark' and populate same as job drop down..
anyone help me please

Comment: You need to post some relevant code, how can we help you this way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.